# Django Multiple User types with a payed system

Tags: django, django-models

I am extremely new to the Django frame work and needed a little more insight. I am currently building a project to have two user types.Example would be a teacher and student type application. The main difference would be that I would like to have one of the users to have a payed tier.
Example: I would love to have it so that the teacher can only log in if payed.

My other question would be.
I already have been working on the project before coming to realize the AbstractUser might be a better solution.

1. Can I get around using AbstractUser with using OnetoOneModels with this type of setup?
2. I found documentation saying it's best to use AbstractUser before any migrations are made, how would I go about changing my project to suit these new requirements "If AbstractUser is best"? If there is no easy way around it I'm not above starting over to make it right.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit your custom user model from AbstractUser and add in it your custom fields.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    height = models.FloatField()
```

For example for user types you can add foreign key field:

```
user_type = models.ForeignKey(
    UserType,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL
)
```

Or you can add some boolean field:

```
is_paid_tier_user = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up finding more in the Django Docs to configure the AbstractUser. I appreciate the help!